# Transformação de uma coluna de um dataframe em data retorna NA

Tags: r

Já encontrei problemas muito similares, mas nenhum chegou aonde estou. Estou tentando ler um arquivo CSV e transformar em Série Temporal.

```
download.file('https://drive.google.com/u/3/uc?id=1hAQfAKXmzwWv0ZEcE2j_kiUcXplHLOSTB&export=download', 
destfile = 'STP.csv')

STP = read.csv2('STP.csv',header = FALSE,';', col.names = c('Data', 'Indice'), skip = 1)
```

Aqui criei o objeto em Dataframe que gerou esta planilha(na verdade a planilha tem 336 entradas mas aqui vao as 20 primeiras)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
STP$Data=as.Date(STPData, format = '%m/%Y')
```

Quando faço isso meu dataframe fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se tento sem o format ele diz que o formato não é não ambíguo.

Passei algumas horas pesquisando no Google casos similares e não consigo entender o que acontece. Já usei `sapply(STP, class)` antes e depois. Antes ele diz que a coluna data é do tipo character e depois, quando NA, como date.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Em vez de compartilhar o arquivo via Google Drive, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Use `dput` ou simule os dados, sua questão não depende exatamente da sua planilha. E remova as referências à biblioteca readr, ela não é usada no código postado.

Comment: O erro vem de a data só ter mês e ano, precisa de um dia. Tente, por exemplo dia 1. `paste0("1/", STP$Data)`.

Answer (score 3):

@rui-barradas já indicou o problema nos comentários, vou estender a resposta.

Uma data é um dia único, a classe Dates exige que sejam especificados dia, mês e ano; formatos parciais são usados apenas para exibição. Sem o dia, não é possível determinar a data; o objeto será da classe date, mas o valor será definido como não disponível (NA):

```
as.Date("11/2011", format = "%m/%Y")
#> [1] NA

as.Date("11/11/2011", format = "%d/%m/%Y")
#> [1] "2011-11-11"
```

Se seus dados são mensais, pode 1) usar um dia fixo para gerar as datas ou 2) usar uma classe feita para armazenar dados mensais (p.e. yearmon, do pacote zoo):

```
datas <- paste0(10:12, "/2011")

as.Date(paste0("01/", datas), format = "%d/%m/%Y")
[1] "2011-10-01" "2011-11-01" "2011-12-01"

zoo::as.yearmon(datas, format = "%m/%Y")
#> [1] "out 2011" "nov 2011" "dez 2011"
```

Se vai usar a classe série temporal e seus dados já forem ordenados e regulares, não precisa do vetor de datas, basta indicar o início e a frequência:

```
ts(1:20, start = c(2011, 11), frequency = 12)
#>      Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
#> 2011                                           1   2
#> 2012   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14
#> 2013  15  16  17  18  19  20
```